# Operator '+' not defined for the type 'x' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to add +1 to my followers but I can't because I am getting errors. I have commented on the error below and I am implementing the flutter DDD by reso coder.

```
@immutable
abstract class ValueObject<T> {
  const ValueObject();
  Either<ValueFailure<T>, T> get value;
  

  /// throws [UnexpextedValueError] containing the [ValueFailure]
  T getOrCrash() {
    // id = identity - same as writing (right) => right
    return value.fold((f) => throw UnexpectedValueError(f), id);
  }

  Either<ValueFailure<dynamic>, Unit> get failureOrUnit {
    return value.fold(
      (l) => left(l),
      (r) => right(unit),
    );
  }

  bool isValid() => value.isRight();

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is ValueObject<T> && other.value == value;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => value.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Value($value)';
}
```

```
class Followers extends ValueObject<int> {
  @override
  final Either<ValueFailure<int>, int> value;
  factory Followers(int input) {
    return Followers._(validateintegerNotNegative(input));
  }
  const Followers._(this.value);
}
```

```
final updatedUser =
            state.user.copyWith(followers: state.user.followers + 1);
```

Error:

> "message": "The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Followers'.\nTry defining the operator '+'."

Comment: What type of value does the parameter ``followers`` accept?

Comment: Most probably ``followers`` accept an object but you're passing an integer. Can you check?

Comment: Presumably you mean `Followers(state.users.followers.value.right + 1)`, or you need to explicitly add an `operator +` to the `Followers` class to do that for you.

Comment: The Followers parameter only accepts integer but i am also trying to make it accept operators like '+' or '-'.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** define `operator +` method

This is changed class:

```
class Followers extends ValueObject<int> {
  @override
  final Either<ValueFailure<int>, int> value;
  factory Followers(int input) {
    return Followers._(validateintegerNotNegative(input));
  }

  Followers operator +(int val) {
    return Followers(value.getOrElse(() => null) + val);
  }

  Followers operator -(int val) {
    return Followers(value.getOrElse(() => null) + val);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return value.getOrElse(() => null).toString();
  }
  const Followers._(this.value);
}
```

How I used it for a test:

```
Followers f = Followers(0);         // 0
f = Followers(f.getOrCrash() + 1);  // 1
f = Followers(f.getOrCrash() + 10); // 11
f = Followers(f.getOrCrash() - 2);  // 9
```

Comment: I am still confused.

Comment: I renewed my answer

Comment: I am sorry I know I would be asking for much but can you rewrite the code by implementing my own valueobject logic because i am using valueobject globally for other classes that don't need to be added or subtracted.

Comment: I don't promise anything. But, in that case, please, recreate your problem here `https://flutlab.io`, and `share` the project - so that I don't guess the code that you have now.

Comment: this is the link https://flutlab.io/ide/522b6884-7a62-4cc0-8102-97d9f3db54de

Comment: please select `Anyone with the link can view` instead `Only invited people can access` because I can't open the link

Comment: Sorry ive changed it  https://flutlab.io/ide/522b6884-7a62-4cc0-8102-97d9f3db54de

Comment: i think the link must be renewed I still can't open it

Comment: Its saying lesson cannot be shared and i don't know what to do

Comment: ok, then push the project to a public github repo, I'll clone it

Comment: Okay, but I thought you were set up the project and not just putting the files in. Please write a code that could correctly initialize objects in the main (). I should see the specified error ("The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Followers'. Try defining the operator '+'.") But not setup the project. You can put the code of main () in your question now.

Comment: unfortunately, I think that I cannot fix your code, there are not enough dependencies, functions. there is no time to finish writing what is missing.

Comment: sorry, this took long. this is the link https://github.com/ahmad-olu/Operator_repo.git

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate. Please can i get i way of contacting you if i have a problem.